# AngularJS directive and controller not binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having troubles figuring out what the problem is: my directive is not updating after editing an item in the list it is showing...

**In my controller:**

```
cvm.getContactpersons = getContactpersons;
cvm.editContactperson = editContactperson;

// Get contactpersons
function getContactpersons(){
    cvm.loadingContacts = true;
    contactpersons.list().then(function(result){
        cvm.contacts = result;
        cvm.loadingContacts = false;
    });
}

// Edit contactperson
function editContactperson() {
    contactpersons.edit(cvm.contact).then(function(result){
        cvm.getContactpersons();
    });
}
```

**Directive for contactperson overview**

```
<contacts-overview
    ng-if="!ContactsCtrl.loadingContacts && ContactsCtrl.contacts.length"
    contacts="ContactsCtrl.contacts"
    filter="ContactsCtrl.searchContact">
</contacts-overview>
```

**JS of directive:**

```
app.directive('contactsOverview', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'contacts-overview.html',
        scope : {
            contacts : '=',
            filter : '='
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindToController: true,
        controller: function(){}
    }
});
```

On page load I call `ContactsCtrl.getContactpersons()`, loading all the contacts. The directive nicely shows a list of contacts. When clicking on a contactperson you can edit it. After editing with `ContactsCtrl.editContactperson()`, I call `ContactsCtrl.getContactpersons()` again but the list is not updating... Any thoughts what is going on? Even the loading-state is not changing...

Comment: Why do you not have the function in the directive's controller? It looks like it's in a page controller. The directive will be passed the ContactsCtrl.contacts just once, at instantiation so it doesn't look like it will ever be updated.

Comment: Because I use this directive for not only contactpersons, but also for "another kind of" contactpersons...